# Play youtube playlist with youtube-dl with shuffling or repeat

Tags: youtube-dl, mpv

I use `mpv` to play a youtube playlist, and it would be extremely cool if I could turn on shuffling and repeat.

Is this possible to do with `youtube-dl`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Omg there is shuffling!

I just looked at the man page for `mpv`, so not with `youtube-dl` directly.

`mpv '<yt-playlist-link>' --no-video --shuffle`

That simple.